# How to detect if docker run and the underlying daemon fully started programmatically?

Tags: bash, docker

I am running a Virtuoso docker and than loading data on it.

I have all this in a bash script. 
Since this command run sequentially loading the data usually fails since Virtuoso didn't fully start yet.

The easy solution is just to add a delay (sleep), and it works. It's a bit dirty solution though.

I found this command

```
docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} $CONTAINER_ID
```

But this only tells if the container is running or not.

Is there a way to check if the daemon on docker fully started (in this case Virtuoso) before loading the data?

Comment: `fully started programmatically` - you need to connect with virtuoso and check if it's available. There's no other way around. You need to test the service.

Comment: @KamilCuk that's what I thought, but still wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the TCP port is open with [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script:

```
container_ip = $(docker inspect --format "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{ .IPAddress }}{{end}}") $CONTAINER_ID
until $(./wait-for-it.sh $container_ip:<virtuoso_port> --timeout=1)
do 
 echo "Virtuoso is not responding"; 
done;
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic process is to define a healthcheck for your application and then check that health state:

```
docker inspect --format '{{.State.Health.Status}}' $container_id
```

The desired output is `healthy`.

For more details on how to define a healthcheck for your image, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

The actual command you define for a healthcheck will vary per application being run inside the container.